# Get json based on url hash

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, onclick

I want to load diffrent json data based on click:

```
<a href="#jsonAlpha">Get Alpha json</a>
<a href="#jsonBeta">Get Beta json</a>
// and so on.
```

The js:

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'domain.com/json?source=jsonAlpha',
    success: function( jsonData ) {
      console.log(jsonData)
    }
  })
});
```

So each hash in the link matches the json source query.

What would be the best way to detect the hash in the clicked link and then pass the hash into the json url?

In other words:

```
if clicked link is href == jsonAlpha add this hash into ajaxUrl
```

Do you get what I mean?

Comment: To confirm, you want the JSON data source to change based on clicking a link?

Comment: jup. that's the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, listen for the `hashchange` event on the `window`. This will occur in cases where the user clicks the link which contains the URL fragment, or they have typed the URL containing the fragment in to the URL bar of the browser:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://www.yourdomain.com/json',
    data: { 
      source: window.location.hash.substring(1)
    },
    success: function( jsonData ) {
      console.log(jsonData)
    }
  })
});
```

Note that I added the scheme to the URL which is required for a cross-domain request. Also note that if this is a cross-domain request then the receiving domain will need to include CORS headers in the response, otherwise you will be blocked from working with the response by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipecdia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: If I understand you correctely this code listenes to changes in the url adress field of the browser wether it is hand typed or trough a link click? (This can't be simulated on codepen then)

Comment: That's correct. I don't know if Codepen have restrictions on this as I don't use it (I find it far too cluttered, and too many clicks to navigate). It works fine on jsFiddle though: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0fpa8q5g/

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `attr()` function to get the `href` of the clicked anchor tag.
Assmuming you are going to append text which is infront of the `#` in your `url`.

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'domain.com/json?source='+$(this).attr('href').slice(1),
    success: function( jsonData ) {
      console.log(jsonData)
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Id like to have the tag behind the `#` so `domain.com#bla` so I'd like to get `bla` and add this to the json url